# Selecting Latitude and Longitude points within a radius

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm using a forumla to select lat/long points in a database given a location and radius however I'm falling just short of it working. The only time I can get the query to work is when i use a radius of 6371km(the size of the world), I figure there is an issue with the forumla but I just cant seem to figure out where...

Here is my sql query

```
   $latitude = $_POST["latitude"]; // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
   $longitude = $_POST["longitude"];; // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
   $rad = $_POST["radius"]; // radius of bounding circle in kilometers
   $R = 6371;// earth's mean radius, km
   $maxLat = $latitude + rad2deg($rad/$R);
   $minLat = $latitude - rad2deg($rad/$R);
    // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
   $maxLon = $longitude + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($latitude)));
   $minLon = $longitude - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($latitude)));



   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Winter#05");

   if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysqli_select_db($con, "appdatabase");


   $result = mysqli_query($con,"select id, PostTitle, SubmitDate, PostVotes, ImagePath, comments, latitude, longitude, acos(sin($latitude)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos($latitude)*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-($longitude))) * $R as D 
   from ( select id, PostTitle, SubmitDate, PostVotes, comments, ImagePath, latitude, longitude 
   from posts where latitude > $minLat and latitude < $maxLat and longitude > $minLon and longitude < $maxLon ) as first_cut 
   where acos(sin($latitude)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos($latitude)*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude) - ($longitude))) * $R < $rad order by D") or die('Errant query:');

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
        $output[]=$row;
   }


   print(json_encode($output));

   mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) and [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: your rad2deg calls don't make any sense. you're basically doing `rad2deg(6371/6371)`. that's just calculating a proportion of two lengths. you need to convert that proportion into radians.

Comment: This expression appears to be wrong (both places it appears): `rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($latitude)))`.  It should be `rad2deg($rad/($R*cos(deg2rad($latitude))))`.  Your other `rad2deg()` calls look right to me, though.

Comment: @MarB not always is it (6371/6371), I was just setting the radius to the largest it can be for debugging purposes. However If i wanted to decrease the radius of points im selecting then I need to adjust $rad

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hmm, tried that. Doesnt appear to be working. Not giving me any results.

Comment: @ErrolGreen: I think the issue is that `$latitude` and `$longitude` are being supplied in the query in units of *degrees*, and the formula expects *radians*. It looks like you are just missing a `RADIANS()` wrapper around those literal values in the SQL text. For debugging, echo out the generated SQL text, before submitting the query to the  database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that it looks like `$latitude` and `$longitude` are being incorporated into the SQL text in units of *degrees*. The formula (as it's implemented in the SQL query) looks like expects the values in those positions to be in *radians*.

---

If I had to read/maintain this code, it would be *much* easier to understand the query if it were written like this:

```sql
SELECT p.id
     , p.PostTitle
     , p.SubmitDate
     , p.PostVotes
     , p.ImagePath
     , p.comments
     , p.latitude
     , p.longitude
     , ACOS( SIN(       (  $latitude ))
           * SIN(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           + COS(       (  $latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.longitude ) -        ( $longitude ))
           ) * $R
       AS D
  FROM posts p
 WHERE p.latitude  > $minLat
   AND p.latitude  < $maxLat 
   AND p.longitude > $minLon
   AND p.longitude < $maxLon 
HAVING D < $rad
 ORDER BY D
```

The great circle distance formula looks okay, except I'm wondering why the `$latitude` and `$longitude` are being provided in units of radians, rather than degrees.

Then I look in the PHP code, lo and behold, those are actually in units of degrees, and I see that a conversion to radians is missing.

All that's missing from the expression that returns distance "D" is the RADIANS function around `$latitude` and `$longitude`

So this:

```
     , ACOS( SIN(       (  $latitude ))
           * SIN(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           + COS(       (  $latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.longitude ) -        ( $longitude ))
           ) * $R
       AS D
```

Gets replaced with

```
     , ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(  $latitude ))
           * SIN(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           + COS(RADIANS(  $latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.longitude ) - RADIANS( $longitude ))
           ) * $R
       AS D
```

If I was maintaining this, I'd also convert this to a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**. At a minimum, I'd properly escape any potentially unsafe values that being incorporated into the SQL text... `mysqli_real_escape_string`

e.g.

```
$sql .= "  + COS(RADIANS( " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$latitude) . " ))"
```

---

I'm suspicious of the calculations of `$minLat`, `$maxLat`, `$minLon`, `$maxLon`. I'd be sure to test those. For testing just the query without those, I could comment out the entire `WHERE` clause, and then calculate the distance `D` for *every* flipping row in the table, and then filter those through the `HAVING` clause.

We do expect that having the predicates in the `WHERE` clause (if done correctly) will give a "bounding box" that will limit the number of rows we need to crank through the great circle calculation.

Eliminating the inline view should improve performance, since MySQL won't have the overhead of materializing a derived table.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was very insightful. After trying your method I'm still not getting any results. although I think its partly to do with the min/max lat lon calculations . I'm going to echo the results and see where that takes me. I'll let you know my findings

Comment: @ErrolGreen: As a test, try removing the WHERE clause restrictions (on the min/max Lat/Lon, and use just the `HAVING` condition with the great circle calculation. You can also remove the `HAVING` clause, and just add a LIMIT after the ORDER BY. (Since that's going to crank through *every*  row, we really only want to do that as a test. (to test just a few rows, replace the reference to the table with an inline view that pulls only a couple of rows. Since the SQL is being dynamically generated, I'd assign it to a variable `$sql = "SELECT ...`, and the `echo` or `vardump` the contents of `$sql`.

Comment: @ErrolGreen:  on another note, for generating the minLon/maxLon, whether you "add" or "subtract" to get the "min" is really going to depend on whether "Lon" is positive or negative. Or, do the addition and subtraction to get `boundingLon1` and `boundingLon2`, and then figure out which of the values is "smaller". (You've got `> minLon` and `< maxLon` inequality comparisons in the SQL. (You need to ensure that `minLon < maxLon` or you won't get any rows back.) HTH

Comment: Aftering removing the HAVING condition, I found out that my radius was radius "D" was extremely high for some reason. turns out that I was missing RADIANS on one of my COS calculations. It works great now. Thank you so much, you've been so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the following and have been pleased with the (relative) accuracy.

```
( 
    3958*3.1415926 * sqrt( 
        ( table.latitude - $latitude ) * ( table.latitude - $latitude ) 
        + cos( table.latitude / 57.29578 ) 
        * cos( $latitude / 57.29578 ) 
        * ( table.longitude - $longitude ) 
        * ( table.longitude - $longitude ) 
    ) / 180
) <= $radius
```

Comment: Thanks for response but how does it calculate the radius of a the circle ?

Comment: @Errol Green: This expression looks like a MySQL implementation of the haversine formula. (Personally, I would have used the `POWER()` function two times, rather than repeating the two expressions two times each.) I think this formula is mathematically equivalent to the great circle distance formula you are using ("spherical law of cosines"), the difference is that this formula has less rounding error when its run through floating point calculations (due to the limited precision of floating point numbers in the computer.) But the rounding error isn't that big, it only affects small distances.